# Switch Text disable tapping

Tags: android, android-switch

Is there anyway to disable tapping on the text of a `Switch`? Currently it toggles the switch which I don't want.

I'm setting my switch text like `messageSwitch.setText("Messaging Enabled");`. This makes the entire switch view receiving taps of the event. Is there any way to disable this?

Answer (score 0):

In your xml, just set it like this:

```
android:clickable="false"
```

or this might be better

```
android:clickable="false"
android:focusable="false"
android:enabled="false"
```

Setting the enabled option to false disables both the text and the switch itself. You can do all of this programatically as well.